# Changing directory of mysql datadir fails

Tags: permissions, mysql

using ubuntu 17.04, mysql 5.7.

I copied the `/var/lib/mysql` to my `/newlocation` with permissions. I manually checked that all of the users and groups and file and folder permissions were the same in the newlocation as in `/var/lib/mysql`.I changed the datadir in the mysql config. I uninstalled apparmor so that is not an issue anymore. The partition on which `/newlocation` is is a different one than `/var/lib/mysql`, but it is mounted in the `fstab` and is also `ext4` so everything should be fine and dandy, but upon trying to start mysql server I receive this error from systemctl

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/newlocation' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

As I've said the files and permissions and users and groups at the `/newlocation` is identical to `/var/lib/mysql`. The only thing I can think of is that it doesn't like the datadir being on a different partition on a different drive, or that there is an issue with the user mysql accessing that location (which is strange because user mysql owns the `/newlocation`)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: "different partition on a different drive" Is that EXT? Or NTFS? If the latter ... your permissions are not set correctly: you need to set them during the mount

Comment: @Rinzwind It is ext4 and I did check the permissions manually.

Comment: @Arun I followed that to the letter barring the apparmor because I've disabled it. no luck

Answer (score 0):

So what appears to have worked was completely removing mysql from the system and then editing the fstab entry to mount the new partition at /var/lib/mysql and then installing mysql again. Not sure if this is a great idea but it seems to have worked

Comment: Weird. By the way: I would have set /var/ as a mountpoint. Seems more logical to do than just /var/lib/mysql.